# Android strange syntax error query sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, select, count

I'm doing a simple query that counts the records ... but I get syntax error here: COUNT (field1). Have you any idea why? thanks

```
String sql = "SELECT _id, field1, field2, field3 COUNT(field1) 
FROM Appoggio GROUP BY field1 ORDER BY field1 ASC";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma after field3

Try using:

String sql = "SELECT _id, field1, field2, field3, COUNT(field1) 
FROM Appoggio GROUP BY field1 ORDER BY field1 ASC";

Comment: You're right, at this time the brain is not very active. thanks